# Monte Carlo and pooling a list of models fitted to multiply imputed data

Tags: r, montecarlo, r-mice, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I created a `lavaan` model out of an existing dataframe and used that model to generate a list of dataframes with (with some data missing from each dataframe). Then I conducted multiple imputation to create a list of `mids` objects (to address the missing data), and then I fit the original `lavaan` model to each of those `mids` objects using `semTools::runMI`. My final product is a list of `lavaan.mi` objects. (I can easily generate get the summary for each `lavaan.mi` object individually or I can make another list of `lavaan.parameterEstimates`/`lavaan.data.frame` objects).

Now that I have a list of these `lavaan.mi` objects in a list called `final_imp`, is there any way to pool the `lavaan.mi` objects together into a single `lavaan.parameterEstimates` object? Or is it impossible since technically each `lavaan.mi` object came from its own unique dataframe (after being generated from the original model)?

```
set.seed(123)
suppressMessages(library(mice))
suppressMessages(library(lavaan))
suppressMessages(library(simsem))
suppressMessages(library(semTools))
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))

data(mtcars)
model <- 'gear ~ carb'
fit <- sem(model, data = mtcars)
make_missing <- miss(package = "mice", m = 2, maxit = 2, seed = 123)

biglist <- sim(
  nRep = 10,
  model = fit,
  n = 5,
  rawData = mtcars,
  miss = make_missing,
  lavaanfun = "sem",
  modelBoot = TRUE,
  seed = 123,
  dataOnly = TRUE)
#> Progress: 1 / 11 
#> Progress: 2 / 11 
#> Progress: 3 / 11 
#> Progress: 4 / 11 
#> Progress: 5 / 11 
#> Progress: 6 / 11 
#> Progress: 7 / 11 
#> Progress: 8 / 11 
#> Progress: 9 / 11 
#> Progress: 10 / 11 
#> Progress: 11 / 11

run_mi <- function(x) { 
  mice::mice(x, m = 2, maxit = 2, seed = 123, printFlag = FALSE)
}

df_imp <- purrr::map(biglist, run_mi)
#> Warning: Number of logged events: 4
#> Warning: Number of logged events: 1

#> Warning: Number of logged events: 1

#> Warning: Number of logged events: 1
#> Warning: Number of logged events: 3
#> Warning: Number of logged events: 1

#> Warning: Number of logged events: 1
#> Warning: Number of logged events: 2
class(df_imp)
#> [1] "list"
class(df_imp[[1]])
#> [1] "mids"

run_sem <- function(x) {
  runMI(model = model, data = x, fun = "sem", miPackage = "mice", seed = 123)
}

final_imp <- purrr::map(df_imp, run_sem)
class(final_imp)
#> [1] "list"
length(final_imp)
#> [1] 10
class(final_imp[[1]])
#> [1] "lavaan.mi"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "semTools"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `summary()` method on a `lavaan.mi` object (returned by the `runMI()` function).  That is the `semTools` analog of `lavaan::parameterEstimates()`, and it returns pooled results. See the `class?lavaan.mi` help page for details about arguments, and other applicable methods.

Comment: I understand that I can use `summary()` on a `lavaan.mi` object (e.g. `summary(final_imp[[1]])`) but I would like to know if it possible to run `summary()` on a list of `lavaan.mi` objects. For `final_imp`, is there any way to return one pooled output, rather than 10 separate outputs?

Comment: The default `summary()` for a list is just to tell you what is in the list: `summary(foo <- list(a = 1:3, b = lm, c = list(d = factor(1:3), e = letters)))`.  Why pool results across different data sets?  I thought your reprex was just using `modelBoot=` to get some quick data sets, but are you actually trying to combine bootstrapping and multiple imputation?  Wu & Jia (2013) recommended bootstrapping after imputation, not before, to save massive computation time imputing 1 rather than multiple data sets. I thought about enabling bootstrap within `runMI()`, but there were complications.

Comment: My eventual goal is to make the original `lavaan` model more sophisticated and test how variations (e.g., in the model, in the predictor matrix, etc.) impact the final outcome; thus, I want to pool across the different multiply imputed datasets to evaluate this outcome. I didn't think about the ramifications of specifying `modelBoot = TRUE` (I assumed this was `simsem::sim`'s default setting, but thank you for the Wu & Jia (2013) reading). I didn't originally plan to combine bootstrapping and MI; I think for this reprex, `modelBoot` can also be `FALSE`.

Comment: It is still not clear exactly what real-world process you are trying to simulate.  If you are trying to simulate a process of analyzing incomplete data using multiple imputation, then for each data set you sample, you will pool results across imputations to get a single (set of) parameter estimate(s) or associated test(s).  To evaluate the frequency properties of those (e.g., bias, Type I error or coverage rates), you would calculate those diagnostics across replications, just as you would with complete data (and what `simsem` is designed to do).  You would not double-pool.